# How to make a function that takes at least a certain amount of time to complete

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, timer

I want to have a function that will always take a minimum amount of time.

For example, the async function that depends on some sort of async code should always atleast take a certain time, even if the async code inside the function is complete.

```
Future<String> function1(prop) async {
  // Set a minimum time
  // Start a timer

  // await async code

  // Check to see if timer is greater then minimum time
  // If so, return
  // Else, await until minimum time and then return
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this using [Stopwatch](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/Stopwatch-class.html) and [Future.Delayed](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future/Future.delayed.html).

```
Future<dynamic> functionThatAlwaysTakesAtleastHalfASecond(prop) async {
  // Start a stopwatch
  Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
  
  // Set a minimum time
  int delayTime = 500;
  stopwatch.start();

  // await async code
  final result = await functionThatTakesLessThenHalfASecond(prop);

  // Check to see if timer is greater then minimum time
  // If so, return
  if (stopwatch.elapsedMilliseconds > delayTime) {
    return result;
  } 
  // Else, await until minimum time and then return
  else {
    return await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: delayTime - stopwatch.elapsedMilliseconds),
        () {
      return result;
    });
  }
}
```